# UISearch searchDisplayController:shouldReloadTableForSearchString: not reloading

Tags: ios

I'm trying to reload a TableViewController based on a given search, the problem is that it doesn't show the found results, it displays only white cells. My code is like this:

FooTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "Foo.h"

@interface FooTableViewController : UITableViewController<UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray * foos;

    UISearchBar * searchBar;
    UISearchDisplayController * searchDisplayController;
    NSMutableArray * searchFoos;
}

@property NSMutableArray * foos;

@end
```

FooTableViewController.m

```
#import "FooTableViewController.h"

#import "FooCell.h"

@interface FooTableViewController ()
@end

@implementation FooTableViewController

@synthesize foos;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

// NSMutableArray foos is populated
- (void) populateFoo;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self populateFoo];
    searchFoos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{   
    int sections = 1;
    if(tableView == self.tableView)
    {
        sections = [foos count];
    }
    // si estamos en vista de búsqueda
    if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        sections = [searchFoos count];
    }

    return sections;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    FooCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[FooCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if(tableView == self.tableView)
    {
        Foo * foo = (Foo *)[foos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.uilabel_name.text = foo.name;
        cell.uilabel_date.text = foo.date;
    }
    if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        Foo * foo = (Foo *)[searchFoos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.uilabel_name.text = foo.name;
        cell.uilabel_date.text = foo.date;
    }

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Search bar delegates

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [searchFoos removeAllObjects];

    for (Foo * foo in foos)
    {
        if([foo.name rangeOfString:searchString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [searchFoos addObject:e];
        }
    }

    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

When I debug searchDisplayController:shouldReloadTableForSearchString, I get positive results for my search terms, but it simply doesn't load any cells. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "FooTableViewController.h"

#import "FooCell.h"

@interface FooTableViewController ()
@end

@implementation FooTableViewController

@synthesize foos;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

// NSMutableArray foos is populated
- (void) populateFoo;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self populateFoo];
    searchFoos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{   
    int rows = 1;
    if(tableView == self.tableView)
    {
        rows = [foos count];
    }
    else
    {
        rows = [searchFoos count];
    }

    return rows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    FooCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[FooCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if(tableView == self.tableView)
    {
        Foo * foo = (Foo *)[foos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.uilabel_name.text = foo.name;
        cell.uilabel_date.text = foo.date;
    }
    else
    {
        Foo * foo = (Foo *)[searchFoos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UILabel * newLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
        newLabel.text = foo.name;
        [foo addSubview: newLabel];
    }

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Search bar delegates

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [searchFoos removeAllObjects];

    for (Foo * foo in foos)
    {
        if([foo.name rangeOfString:searchString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [searchFoos addObject:e];
        }
    }
    return YES;
}

@end
```